# How to place a Transparent Flash over site and keep underlying site usable (focus, clicks, formes submitting...etc)

Tags: javascript, css, flash, iframe

We are trying to place a flash with transparency that covers an iframe. The iframe will load any external website.

Is there a way to setup the page so the flash is shown but the underlying site is still usable (focus, clicks, formes submitting...etc).

Comment: For the underlying site, are you refering to the site inside the iframe or the site that contains the iframe and flash?

Comment: the underlying site = the site that is loaded inside the iframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

once you place an item above another element or iframe that item (flash in this case) will be the topmost element and will always be the element that is clicked...

although, how about a mix of overflows and positioning...

- target the iframe and give it relative positioning...
- put div inside iframe with very small width and height high z-index as well and absolute positioning...
- put the flash in the div which is inside the iframe...
- make sure the div which wraps the flash object is overflow:visible...

that may make the rest of the iframe click-able

that is off the top of my head, may work don't know...

let me know if that works...

Comment: I don't think it's possible to get or set elements inside the iframe when it is loading a site from another domain. Security purposes.

I'm using jQuery to try solution, and I get this error:
Permission denied for <http://client.provokat.ca> to get property HTMLDocument.nodeType from <http://facebook.com>.

client.provokat.ca being my domain, and facebook being the site that I load in the iframe.